# Get additional data in laravel select query

Tags: php, laravel, select, eloquent

When i use select query in laravel i am given additional data.

My query

```
MyModal::where('state', 1)
        ->select('code as popupContent', 'latitude as lat','longitude as lng')
        ->take(3)
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
```

Returned data:

```
[
  [
    "popupContent" => "260563"
    "lat" => 35.765014
    "lng" => 51.333209
    "update_time" => null
    "rooms_number" => null
  ]
  [
    "popupContent" => "891962"
    "lat" => 35.794741
    "lng" => 51.391965
    "update_time" => null
    "rooms_number" => null
  ]
  [
    "popupContent" => "477845"
    "lat" => 35.723649
    "lng" => 51.320682
    "update_time" => null
    "rooms_number" => null
  ]
]
```

In the code above, fields `update_time` and `rooms_number` are added

I want to give this data:

```
[
  [
    "popupContent" => "260563"
    "lat" => 35.765014
    "lng" => 51.333209
  ]
  [
    "popupContent" => "891962"
    "lat" => 35.794741
    "lng" => 51.391965
  [
    "popupContent" => "477845"
    "lat" => 35.723649
    "lng" => 51.320682
  ]
]
```

Comment: share your model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe override `$append` property

```
public $appends = ['update_time', 'rooms_number'];
```

For hidden the appended columns use this

```
MyModal::where('state', 1)
    ->select('code as popupContent', 'latitude as lat','longitude as lng')
    ->take(3)
    ->get()
    ->makeHidden(['update_time', 'rooms_number'])
    ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's still in your model.
You can try:

```
$items =  DB::table('tableName')
->where('state', 1)
->select('code as popupContent', 'latitude as lat','longitude as lng')
->take(3)->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code:

```
    YourModel::select('code as popupContent', 'latitude as lat','longitude as lng')
    ->where('state', 1)
    ->take(3)
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: Have you tried? I have faced same issue and this works for me.

Comment: best is, to try any given code first before down voting

Comment: I downvoted it because it does exactly the same thing as the op did. The result of trying it will be the same as the one reported. The fact that you change the order of 2 methods when calling them will not change anything unless the code is very badly written. Trust me, it is not the case for Laravel to fail in such a trivial way.